# DRCSIM: Time sync and coordination

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Cross posted to theroboticschallenge.org forums.

Can we get an ntp/ptp server operating on the simulation computer that the field and OCS computers can sync to?
Can we add wall clock to the API clock message?

Together, these will allow us to keep track of the delay between time stamped messages and the time on receiving computer.

On the actual system it would make more sense to have the robot sync to the OCS (assuming it has GPS/internet time server connection), but may be simpler to have the simulation cloud provide service here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1073/drcsim:-time-sync-and-coordination/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-01-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tkoolen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/64/tkoolen/) on 2013-01-28**:
We are also very interested in this feature. See the following open issue on the drcsim bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/101/provide-synchronous-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See Gerkey's answer on
[https://www.theroboticschallenge.org/forum/default.aspx?Function\_fst=ViewThread&ThreadID_fin=121](https://www.theroboticschallenge.org/forum/default.aspx?Function%5C_fst=ViewThread&ThreadID_fin=121)

filed a feature request for running an NTP server: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/cloudsim/issue/11/add-ntp-server

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) with karma: 298 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-01-28**:
This doesn't address second part of adding both sim and wall time to the clock message.  It would seem we would need both keep track properly